# Saving nested schema in moongose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I have Two models

**first model**

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
// create a schema
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name       : String,
  description: String,
  active     : Boolean,
  createdDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updatedDate: {type: Date, default: ''}
});
var category       = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
module.exports     = category;
```

**second model**

```
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
// create a schema
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  product_name: String,
  manufacturer: String,
  category    : {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}
});
var user          = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports    = user;
```

**This is the model I used:**

```
module.exports.CreateProdct = function(Channel_Object, callback) {
  product = new Product({
    product_name: Channel_Object.product_name,
    manufacturer: Channel_Object.manufacturer,
    category    : Channel_Object.category,
  });

  product.save(function(err, customer) {

    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      callback(customer);

  });
}
```

**when I was saving the product schema I got an error:**

```
{ category:
  { [CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{ name: 'bus', descriptio
   n: 'dskflsdflsdkf', active: true }" at path "category"]
```

**This is the json for project**

```
{
  "product_name": "ppsi",
  "manufacturer": "fanta",
  "category"    : {
    "name"       : "bus",
    "description": "dskflsdflsdkf",
    "active"     : true
  }
}
```

This is JSON for the product model. I embedded the category in product model it shows "Cast to ObjectID failed for value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `product schema` you have defined `category` as a referenced field `(ref : 'Category')` . It expects an `ObjectId`, but in your `CreateProdct` function, you are passing whole Object to it.

That is why it is showing this error :

> [CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{ name: 'bus',
>   description: 'dskflsdflsdkf', active: true }" at path "category"].

Try saving the `category` first,and then on `successful creation` of `category` pass its `_id` to `product` document and then `save` it.

**Try this:**

```
module.exports.CreateProdct = function(Channel_Object, callback) {

  var category = new Category(Channel_Object.category);
  category.save(function(err,category)
  {
    if(!err)
    {
      product = new Product({
        product_name: Channel_Object.product_name,
        manufacturer: Channel_Object.manufacturer,
        category: category._id
      });

      product.save(function(err2,customer){

        if(err)
          console.log(err2)
        else  
          callback(customer);

     });
    }
    else{
      console.log(err);
      //handle the case where it throws error too.
    }
  })

}
```